# Javascript button active when site loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a site with a responsive design for smartphones etc.
The menu goes away and a button appears to open the menu when you are using a smartphone.
To activate the button i implemented this javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menubutton').click(function() {
      $('.nav').slideToggle('slow');
    });
  });
```

But when i go on the website with my smartphone the menu is standard openend. But i want that if i go on the site the menu is closed. How can i do this?

PS:
Sorry i never really worked with javascript before :)

Comment: What framework (if any) are you using to make your site responsive?

Answer (score 2):

Do with css [`media query`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) { //fix size as you wish
    .nav{
    display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will trigger on all devices and not just on mobile devices like the OP wanted

Answer (score 1):

You have to use media query (in your CSS file) and specify at what point should it go to a hamburger menu.

The following media query will trigger the menu to *hide* as soon as the screen size is 767px:

```
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
}
```